# Is it possible to modify a C program which is running?

Tags: c, linux, binary, system

i was wondering if it is possible to modify a piece of C program (or other binary) while it is running ?

I wrote this small C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t gcui32_val_A = 0xAABBCCDD;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

    uint32_t ui32_val_B = 0;
    uint32_t ui32_cpt = 0;

    printf("\n\n Program SHOW\n\n");

    while(1) {

        if(gcui32_val_A != ui32_val_B) {
            printf("Value[%d] of A : %x\n",ui32_cpt,gcui32_val_A);
            ui32_val_B = gcui32_val_A;
            ui32_cpt++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With a Hex editor i'm able to find "0xAABBCCDD" and modify it when the program is stopped. The modification works when I relauch the program. Cool !

I would like to do this when the program s running is it possible ?

Here is a simple example to understand the phenomena and play a little with it but my true project is bigger.

- I have an old DOS game called Dangerous Dave.
- I'm able to modify the tiles by simply editing the binary (thanks to http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/Dangerous_Dave)
- I developped a small editor that do this pretty well and had fun with it.
- I launch the DOS game by using DOSBOX, it works !

I would like to do this dynamically when the game is running. Is it possible ?

PS : I work under Debian 64bit

regards

Comment: when loaded, the code resides in read-only segments in most systems, but you can change the data by attaching a debugger to it and change data dynamically if you have the symbols

Comment: Yeah, it's possible in principle. A debugger may attach to a process and if you pause it, even allow you to modify the process memory (including executable pages). It's not trivial to accomplish however.

Comment: @IporSircer.: Seems got the context wrong. but here also you ar ebasically changing the mode...from kernel to user. Well to the overall notion the answer contradicts thinking that Op wants to run the user level program without changing the mode (kernel vs user mode). I will delete the answer as it clearly not the intention of the author.

Comment: You can see in the tutorial you linked *If a debugger attaches itself to another program already loaded in memory, it requests special permission from the operating system to take control of the program for the purpose of debugging*. This is the idea I wanted to emphasize. But again if you use a debugger you are basically changing the code which is being debugged. And really nobody was thinking about changing a code which is being run on kernel mode(it's not possible). Neither the C language nor any compiler supports it. But yes I guess I missed the debugger.

Comment: Is your DOS game open source? Did you consider to use some open source game or game engine? Is you overall goal to play that game, or to make a better game? What are your programming skills?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all that replies.
This DOS game is not open source but is abandonware and can be found here http://www.bestoldgames.net/eng/old-games/dangerous-dave.php
It's the first game i've played on my very first computer so is all about nostalgia and a good reason tu try hacking/modding no further application

I'm software embedded system engineer and the more i know is about DSP and baremetal (without OS) application. I know basics about linux system but happy to learn ;)

Comment: Is your goal to rewrite *Dangerous Dave* as proper, open source, game for Linux, or is just to play that game on Linux? Your question should have additional motivation and context (so consider editing it once again, please).

Comment: No problem I will precise my goal !

If you go to this page http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/Dangerous_Dave, you can see that at the offset 0x26e0a you have an array for each of 10 levels. Each level is a map of 10x100 tiles (each tiles is coded further in the code as 16x16 image but doesn't matter here). In the array of 1000 cell (10x100) you can set a value from 0 (void player can pass) to 52 to chose the tile you want to show in your map.

Comment: If you edit the binary game file with hex editor you can change these values and launching the game with DOS BOX to see your game level modifications

- I don't want to rewrite the game
- I'm already able to launch it in linux through DOSBOX
- I'm just looking for a way to change the value of the array dynamically (by an external program in C, shell script, or hex editor,..) in order to modifying the map during I play just for fun

Comment: Please don't add comments to your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it. If possible, show some [MCVE] - otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Also tell us how much efforts are you willing to spend (you might need weeks of work, is it worthwhile just to play some old game; you need to decide!)

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if it is possible to modify a piece of C program (or other binary) while it is running ?

Not in standard (and portable) [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)). Read the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specification to check. Notice that most of the time in practice, it is not the C [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) program (made of several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) which is running, but an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) result of some [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) & [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

---

However, on Linux (e.g. Debian/Sid/x86-64) you could use some of the following tricks (often with function pointers):

- use [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), so design your program to accept them and define conventions about your plugins. A plugin is a shared object [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file (some `*.so`) containing [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (so it should be compiled with specific options). You'll use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to do the [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) of the plugin.
- use some [JIT-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library, like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit).
- alter your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (not recommended) manually, using [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) and [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html); then you could overwrite something in a [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) (you really should not do that). This might be tricky (e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)) and brittle.
- perhaps use debug related facilities, either with [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) or by scripting or [extending](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) the `gdb` debugger.

I suggest to play a bit with `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) and try at least to run in some terminal the following commands

```
 cat /proc/self/maps
 cat /proc/$$/maps
 ls /proc/$$/fd/
```

(and read enough things to understand their outputs) to understand a bit more what a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) "is".

So overwriting your [text segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) (if you really need to do that) is possible, but perhaps more tricky than what you believe !

<sup>(do you mind working for several weeks or months simply to improve some old gaming experience?)</sup>

---

Read also about [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) programming languages (try Common Lisp with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)), about [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating), about [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)), about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), and about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (I recommend: [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) & [OsDev](http://osdev.org/) wiki)

---

> I work under Debian 64bit

I suppose you have programming skills and do know C. Then you should read [ALP](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) or some newer Linux programming book (and of course look into [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html) and other man pages etc...)

BTW, in your particular case, perhaps the "OS" is DOSBOX (acting as some virtual machine). You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on DOSBOX (or on other commands or processes), or study its source code.

---

You mention games in your question. If you want to code some, consider libraries like [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), [GTK+](http://gtk.org/), ....

Comment: Thanks for all your links 
I'm software embedded system engineer and the more i know is about DSP and baremetal (without OS) application. I know basics about linux system but happy to learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify piece of code while running in C. You got to have pointer to your program memory area, and compiled pieces of code that you want to change. Naturally this is considered to be a dangerous practice, with lot of restrictions, and with many possibilities for error. However, this was practice at olden times when the memory was precious.

Comment: Can you be more specific or giving an example because all attempt I've made that way have ended by a "Segmentation Fault " ^^

Comment: In practice, see the third bullet of my answer. You probably need to use `mprotect` or `mmap`and you really should practically not try to change your code segment. And in the details it could be quite tricky and very brittle. So I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: I have found a smart and thorough description of it: https://shanetully.com/2013/12/writing-a-self-mutating-x86_64-c-program/